# How to test custom configuration section in web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My MVC Web API application has a custom configuration section which is used by the application for config values.

I want to test whether the custom configuration section values populated in the web.config file are correct and `GetSection` is able to read them correctly. Is there any way to test this without creating another config file for nunit with the exact same values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to test this without creating another config file for nunit with the exact same values?

Yes, you can do this as follows:

```
Configuration OpenWebConfiguration(string configurationFilePath)
{
    var configurationFileInfo = new FileInfo(configurationFilePath);
    var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configurationFileInfo.DirectoryName, true, configurationFileInfo.Name);
    var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
    wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
    return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
}

...
var c = OpenWebConfiguration(pathToWebConfigFile);
var section = c.GetSection(sectionName);
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to test this without creating another config file for nunit with the exact same values?

No, there isn't. You are required to have a config file in order to test the custom section. And what better place than a unit test project for that? It's seems like the perfect place.

For example you could have the following projects in your solution:

- MyApp.Configuration (containing the custom section and elements)
- MyApp.Configuration.Tests (containing an `app.config` file allowing to test your custom config section)

Comment: The problem is I want to test the web.config itself and I dont want to update the test config file every time changes are made

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, just in case you are looking for an answer on how to avoid adding a separate config file to your Test project and then sync the main config file with your test file, [**here's a link**](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/09/26/VS2012-Create-multiple-file-links-with-a-drag-and-drop-between-two-projects.aspx) that describes a neat way of adding the original app/web.config as a link in Test project. You'd essentially be dealing with a single config file.
**[This blog](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000589.html)** talks about an alternative approach by using [TestConigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testconfiguration.configurationsection.aspx)
and the ExeConfigurationFileMap (you may use the equivalent [WebConfigurationFileMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationfilemap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))